# SQL Insert in first empty column in a row MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have looked around for a solution to my problem but can’t see anything similar online.
I am working on an SQL script to insert values in the first null column in a row.

Am getting this MySQL error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' WHERE ID = 89 ' .

This is my script. Am testing by trying to insert 52 into the first empty column in the row with ID=89.

```
$item3 = 52;

$sql="insert into TABLENAME set 
GAME1 = case when GAME1 = '' then $item3 else GAME1 end,
GAME2 = case when GAME2 = '' and GAME1 <> '' then $item3 else GAME2 end,
GAME3 = case when GAME3 = '' and GAME1 <> ''and GAME2 <> '' then $item3 else GAME3 end
WHERE ID = 89 ";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, actually I would say the problem is not your query but your database design. If you have a one-to-many relationship , you shouldn't multiply the fields in the table to match the "many" limit, but write those records in a separate table.

Comment: `INSERT` is for adding new rows, `UPDATE` is for modifying existing rows. It doesn't make sense to use `WHERE` in `INSERT`.

Comment: you can start learning the basics first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `update`

```
$sql="update TABLENAME set 
GAME1 = case when GAME1 = '' then $item3 else GAME1 end,
GAME2 = case when GAME2 = '' and GAME1 <> '' then $item3 else GAME2 end,
GAME3 = case when GAME3 = '' and GAME1 <> ''and GAME2 <> '' then $item3 else GAME3 end
WHERE ID = 89 ";
```