# Compare table field values to insert new value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I inherited a website with an existing database structure. I have one table (`TABLE1`) that has something like the following structure:

```
POSITION_1_TAGS_PERMITTED  | POSITION_2_TAGS_PERMITTED | POSITION_3_TAGS_PERMITTED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CD                         | EN,CS                     | TECH,CS
```

`TABLE1` has this structure up to 20 columns.

I then have another table (`TABLE2`) that stores the selected value (also has 20 columns):

```
POS1_SEL_SYMBOL | POS2_SEL_SYMBOL | POS3_SEL_SYMBOL | POS4_SEL_SYMBOL
---------------------------------------------------------------------
A               | AAPL            |                 | AA
```

I have the tags for the selected variable in this case the tag for my variable is `CS`. I'd like to find the position in `TABLE1` that has the allowed tags and then look in `TABLE2` to see if that position already has an entry in it. In this case it would identify position 3 as the column to add my entry to and then I would write a new update statement to add that entry to the database. Is there an easy way to do this with the column format of my database?

EDIT: If there are multiple tags for the variable I'd like it to search the permitted tags column for any value in it. I tried to update my SQL statement to be something like the following:

```
SELECT eventid, 
CASE 
WHEN (FIND_IN_SET("S&P", POSITION_1_TAGS_PERMITTED) OR FIND_IN_SET("CS", POSITION_1_TAGS_PERMITTED)) AND POS1_SEL_SYMBOL = ""
THEN 1 
END AS found_col 
FROM TABLE1 
JOIN TABLE2 
USING (eventid) 
WHERE EVENTID='159'
```

This query doesn't give me the same results as just searching for CS did.

Comment: How do you decide, with tag CS, between Position 2 and Position 3?

Comment: @BeetleJuice Select the first empty column in TABLE2. If position 2 would be blank then I would insert it there. In this example, position 2 is already full so it would need to go to position 3.

Comment: Is there any column that relates the rows in the two tables?

Comment: do the tables have just one row? If not, how do you know which row from table 2 should be matched up with a row from table 1?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, sorry. There is an EVENTID field that is the key that links the two tables.

Comment: You can use `FIND_IN_SET('CS', POSITION_#_TAGS_PERMITTED)` to test a column in `TABLE1`.

Comment: @BeetleJuice There is an EVENTID field that is the key that links the two tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT eventid, 
    CASE
        WHEN FIND_IN_SET('CS', POSITION_1_TAGS_PERMITTED) AND POS1_SEL_SYMBOL = ''
        THEN 1
        WHEN FIND_IN_SET('CS', POSITION_2_TAGS_PERMITTED) AND POS2_SEL_SYMBOL = ''
        THEN 2
        WHEN FIND_IN_SET('CS', POSITION_3_TAGS_PERMITTED) AND POS3_SEL_SYMBOL = ''
        THEN 3
        ...
        WHEN FIND_IN_SET('CS', POSITION_20_TAGS_PERMITTED) AND POS20_SEL_SYMBOL = ''
        THEN 20
    END AS found_col
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 USING (eventid)
```

See [SQL Insert in first empty column in a row MySQL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422569/sql-insert-in-first-empty-column-in-a-row-mysql-error) for an `UPDATE` query that you could adapt using the above structure so that you update the field that's found rather than just returning the column number. But with 20 columns, that query will get really long.

Comment: dude how did you learn so much about SQL? Thanks for the `FIND_IN_SET` tip. New food for brain.

Comment: This is great. What if I tag had multiple that I was searching for? If in this case `CS` was `CS,EN`. Would it search for both of those in the POSITION_X_TAGS_PERMITTED?

Comment: You have to combine two `FIND_IN_SET` calls with `AND`: `FIND_IN_SET('CS', POSITION_X_TAGS_PERMITTED) AND FIND_IN_SET('EN', POSITION_X_TAGS_PERMITTED)`.

Comment: Barmar, I tried to do the OR like you said because it could go into any spot that has an allowable tag. I updated my question with my attempt so you can see what I tried.

Comment: Why would you expect it to give the same result as just searching for `CS`? The whole point is that it should also look for `S&P`.

Comment: @Barmar As long as it finds one of them it's ok. It doesn't need to find both. So if `S&P` is there but not in my permitted tags but `CS` is there then it should select that column. That is why I tried to do an OR statement.

Comment: I understand that. But you said "This query doesn't give the same results as just searching for CS". That's the point, isn't it? You want different results.

Comment: It should give the same results with the sample rows you showed, since there's no `S&P` in the data. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: @Bamar, you are right. I didn't go far enough with my numbering. It's working as expected now. Thank you, you're a genius.